# Castle Windsor: how to overwrite a component registration via xml configuration

Tags: xml, components, castle-windsor, overwrite

I'm trying to overwrite a component registration (done via xml) with another one (in another xml, loaded via code using `container.Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("..."))` that has the same component id, but i receive an error saying:

> "Component COMP_ID could not be registered. There is already a component with that name.
>   Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify
>   a unique name."

The thing is, i in fact actually would like to *modify the existing component*, to be able to define basic wiring in a basic castle.xml file and then overwrite it, in another custom.xml file, loaded after the basic one.

I'm trying to use the same component id because a tought it would have rewritten the previous registration.

The reality is that i would like to change wich implementation is used to respond to a service, the component id is just a try that i've done. Since Castle has a policy of first-registration-wins, it would be enough for example to switch to a last-registration-wins, for example.

### Concrete example

Let's use the example of an `ILogger` interface.

The basic castle.xml (loaded *always*) would be like this:

```
<component id="logger" service="ILogger" type="NullLogger" ></component>
```

The castle.dev.xml file (loaded *only* in the dev ambient, after the default one) would look like this:

```
<component id="logger" service="ILogger" type="AspNetTraceLogger" ></component>
```

The castle.prod.xml file (loaded *only* in production ambient, after the default one, *instead* of the dev one) would look like this:

```
<component id="logger" service="ILogger" type="SqlServerLogger" ></component>
```

Now: for each of these configurations, I would like to say "respond to ILogger requests with this impl", so I need to have only one of them to respond to requests for ILogger at each time.

Anyone have any idea?

#### update

I'll add: as of now i'm using a, shall we say, "reverse overwriting" technique, where i load the overwriting files "first", before the corresponding "default" ones. In this way, since the policy is first-wins, i can declare them as overwrites, even though internally they are declared before. The problem with this approach is when i have an interface that **i know** will be implemented more than once (say, IWhateverListener): in this case i cannot remove the other ones already registered, and cannot use the first-wins solution because later on i'll use a ResolveAll() and the "default ones" will be used too.

Comment: what's the concrete scenario?

Comment: @Mauricio: like i said I can't do this via fluent registration or similiar (i can only use code to load some configuration **via xml files**), and cannot recompile for changes. And what i would like to obtain, is to have a functioning basic wiring that lets the app work, and then have the ability to use another file to overwrite some previous registration for the **same service**. I hope to have clarified my needs.

Comment: that's not a concrete scenario... I'm asking about that because maybe you should be using something like a subdependency resolver or a handler selector instead.

Comment: @Mauricio: ok, to givre you a more concrete idea: i have an ILogger interface, and would like to use, by default, a NullLogger. For the "dev" ambient I would like to use the AspNetTraceLogger, in the "test" area the SqlLogger and in production a MultiLogger (which has a parameter of type ILogger[] with 3 different loggers as sub-loggers).

Now: for each of these configurations, I would like to say "respond to ILogger requests with this impl", so I need to have only **one** of them to respond to requests for ILogger at each time.

btw: this is just an example, but it's a real one.

Comment: that *is* a concrete scenario, you should put it on the question instead of a comment.

Comment: @Mauricio: you're right, thanks. I've now updated the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3495/discussion-between-njy-and-mauricio-scheffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to register several components with the same ID, or try to hack around it.

If you must use XML, take a look at [defines and ifs](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/defines.html).

Otherwise just use different [installers](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx), one for each environment, and at application startup register the one you want

Comment: defines and ifs seem to be what i needed. I'll make a couple of tests and then i'll mark this answer as approved. Btw, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, this solved this particular problem! Btw i'm still wondering why ComponentModel.AddService(Type) seems to add a type forwarding to an already registered component, but it doesn't work... anyway thanks.

Comment: @njy: how is ComponentModel related to this? I didn't see any mention of it in this question... please create a new question.

Comment: it was another possibility i was playing with, hacking around with already registered components using the available API, but didn't work very well. Anyway yeah, i didn't explicitly mentioned this try before. Thanks.